# does google webmaster track clicks on deeplinks or best way to capture deeplink clicks on seo results

Tags: seo, google-analytics, google-search-console, deeplinks

On google search results page on mobile browser. If native application is installed google shows the option of **opening the link in app / on broswer**.

In that scenario, does that click gets captured in google webmaster click report ?

What is the best way to capture these deep links through webmaster or any other tool ?

Below image clearly suggests that google has given user option to open in app / or in browser.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can track these click from Google webmaster (Search console)

First let me breakdown all the process and explain what is deeplinking and app indexing.

App indexing appears on Google when someone search for the brand name or anything related to it, your app will appear from google play or itunes with "Download" link.

Deep linking appears on any page of your website and you can open the app through the app if your app/website support deeplinking.

To track deeplinking click and app installs you have to add your application on Google webmaster as a new property then verify your website from Google play, here you will have a connection from the website to the app and follow all the instructions to support deep linking.

after one week Google will start give you the numbers in search console (installs and pages) and you can track everything you want.

This resource will help you from google
https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html

Comment: But I am asking about app indexing primarily. So it is about app is already installed on user's device and Google shows the app link on search result as I have also shown in screenshot.

Comment: If the users don't have your app, a regular web page will appear for them, but if they installed it they will go to the app (deep linking)

Comment: Yes, that is true. But how can i track them separately? Did we get a attribution for them in webmaster ?

Comment: Yes, after adding your application as a property in google webmaster and verify it through play store you can access the search console for it and you will have two option from Search Analytics (Search Appearance)
1 - Search Result Link
2 - Install app button

Comment: OK thanks, I will try this and mark this answer as correct if this works for us.

Comment: This works well and we get a nice dashboard with required analytics. Thanks mate !!